# react-rte (Rich Text Editor): how to implement inline style for custom components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, draftjs

`react-rte` is a Rich Text Editor based on `draft-js`.  My goal is to customize the toolbar components with, e.g., material ui react components. Reading through the react-rte docs, I think that there are two styling hooks:

1. `toolbarConfig` for CSS ([link](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte#toolbar-customization)); and
2. `customControls` for completely overriding components ([as seen in demo](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte/blob/master/src/EditorDemo.js#L51)).

I believe that my use case calls for `customControls`, but from the provided demo (see below) I am not able to understand how to hook the custom components back into rte's functionality. For example, if I render a custom button component for BOLD, how does this button get the default functionality that would have gone to the default button provided by `toolbarConfig`?

**editor demo with customControls**:

```
<RichTextEditor
  value={value}
  onChange={this._onChange}
  className="react-rte-demo"
  placeholder="Tell a story"
  toolbarClassName="demo-toolbar"
  editorClassName="demo-editor"
  readOnly={this.state.readOnly}
  customControls={[
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    (setValue, getValue, editorState) => {
      let choices = new Map([
        ['1', {label: '1'}],
        ['2', {label: '2'}],
        ['3', {label: '3'}],
      ]);
      return (
        <ButtonGroup key={1}>
          <Dropdown
            choices={choices}
            selectedKey={getValue('my-control-name')}
            onChange={(value) => setValue('my-control-name', value)}
          />
        </ButtonGroup>
      );
    },
    <ButtonGroup key={2}>
      <IconButton
        label="Remove Link"
        iconName="remove-link"
        focusOnClick={false}
        onClick={() => console.log('You pressed a button')}
      />
    </ButtonGroup>,
  ]}
/>
```

my currently invalid implementation:

```
<RichTextEditor
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  customControls={rteCustomControls}
/>

...

const inlineStyleButtonControls = [
  { label: "format_bold", style: "BOLD", component: FormatBoldIcon },
  { label: "format_italic", style: "ITALIC", component: FormatItalicIcon },
  {
    label: "format_underlined",
    style: "UNDERLINE",
    component: FormatUnderlinedIcon,
  },
];

const rteCustomControls = [
  (setValue, getValue, editorState) => {
    return inlineStyleButtonControls.map((button, i) => (
      <IconButton
        key={i}
        color="inherit"
        aria-label={button.label}
        selectedKey={getValue(button.style)}
        onClick={value => setValue(button.style, value)}
      >
        <button.component />
      </IconButton>
    ));
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is purely to modify the display, you should be able to target the buttons via CSS to change their displays, just like you would target any other DOM element.

Change element display via CSS.

```
RichTextEditor button:nth-child(1){
    background-image: url('/icon1.svg');
}
RichTextEditor button:nth-child(2){
    background-image: url('/icon2.svg');
}
```

Or, change element display via javascript

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorsAll('RichTextEditor button')).forEach((el)=>{
    // Modify element here
})
```

If you also want to modify the button's functionality, you can look at the [code](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte/blob/master/src/lib/EditorToolbar.js) where they are defined, and potentially add them in as custom controls.

Comment: I've long since migrated from `draft-js` to `slate.js`, so I'm probably not going to go back to verify this answer. If someone else does, however, happy to give you the check @gieoon!